# Selecting a content type from youtube API

Tags: php, xml, youtube, simplexml

I have an xml feed from the youtube API. So far I have successfully lifted the title,thumbnail, ratings etc. However I am struggling to parse the content url from the following feed.

```
<feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/'>
<entry>
<media:group>
<media:content url='http://www.youtube.com/v/ZTUVgYoeN_b?f=gdata_standard...' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' medium='video' isDefault='true' expression='full' duration='215' yt:format='5'/>

<media:content url='rtsp://rtsp2.youtube.com/ChoLENy73bIAEQ1kgGDA==/0/0/0/video.3gp' type='video/3gpp' medium='video' expression='full' duration='215' yt:format='1'/>

<media:content url='rtsp://rtsp2.youtube.com/ChoLENy73bIDRQ1kgGDA==/0/0/0/video.3gp' type='video/3gpp' medium='video' expression='full' duration='215' yt:format='6'/>

</media:group>
</entry>
</feed>
```

Below is my code so far. I believe this has worked for other items because I was not selecting from multiple nodes i.e. there is only one title, thumbnail url etc...

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $xml_feed_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$xml = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$feed = produce_XML_object_tree($xml);
$entry = $feed->entry;
$media = $entry->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
$urla=$media->content->attributes();
$url=$urla["url"];

function produce_XML_object_tree($raw_XML) 
{
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
try 
    {
    $xmlTree = new SimpleXMLElement($raw_XML);
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {
    // Something went wrong.
    $error_message = 'SimpleXMLElement threw an exception.';
    foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error_line) 
        {
        $error_message .= "\t" . $error_line->message;
        }

    trigger_error($error_message);
    return false;
    }
return $xmlTree;
}
```

How can I select one of these content types?

Comment: There's no `src` attribute in that XML you've shown... there's a URL in a `url` attribute, so isn't that what you should be reading?

Comment: Whoops! I lifted the wrong bit of code. I have updated it. That wasn't the issue btw.

Comment: You should probably explain what `$media` is, too. There's not just one way to parse XML in PHP. We have no idea what that variable is.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I swear I'm not a noob..

Comment: You have not clarified anything. What's `$entry`? Not whats in it, but *what code are you using to parse this XML*? Is it a library? One of the ones built into PHP (there are several)? One you downloaded somewhere?

Comment: There we go. [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)!

Comment: My bad. Hopefully this is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

To select one of the content types I just had to use a simple index. Hopefully this is a lesson I only need to learn once:

```
$urla=$media->group->content[0]->attributes();
$url=$urla["url"];
```